# Save copy of sheet's table object's values only

Tags: vba, excel

I've found a macro to save a copy of my Excel's workbook. I'd like to refine the macro to:

- save a copy specific table object;
- save only the values of that table (not the formulas or formatting);

The current VBA script is:

```
Sub Publish()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:= "C:\myfolder\mypublisheddata.xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the part to get the table object is: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that the folder "C:\myfolder" already exists, because if not, the macro will *not* create it but fail.

To save as a normal file (.xlsx):

```
Sub Publish()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy
    Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True, "C:\myfolder\mypublisheddata.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Maybe you dont want to close the new WB immediately, you can use SaveAs instead of Close.

If you really need to save as xlsm macro-enabled, the above method might fail , you'll have to do it this way:

```
Sub Publish()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy
    Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\myfolder\mypublisheddata.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error 400 after the data is copied in the new workbook.

Comment: @Benjamin was the copy operation successful though?

Comment: @Benjamin, it is because of saving as xlsm. It has to be done differently in this case. Is saving as .xlsx ok for you?If not, I can do the necessary modifications.

Comment: @Benjamin Please use the last piece of code if you do need to save the new workbook in macro-enabled (xlsm) format.

Comment: It successfully copied the data yes. I do not need xlsm since I only want the values and nothing else on the file.

Comment: Okay, I tried using xlsx extension and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, there are some "Past Special" cases, one of them only pastes values: `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, ...`